# How to setup my own nameservers with a shared DNS service on my VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, nameserver

So I want to have my own nameservers, like ns1.mydomain.com and ns2 and I have the following things:

- my domain (with godaddy)
- a VPS with 1 IP
- a DNS shared service with access to cPanel and ns1.hostingcompany.com and ns2.hostingcompany.com

So, it's possible to use their shared DNS service and get my own nameservers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your VPS as primary for your DNS, then use a DNS replication service as secondary. This is simple and gives best reliability.

For your VPS: install and configure a DNS software. [BIND](http://www.isc.org/software/bind) is popular. [djbdns](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html) is good.

As DNS replication (aka secondary DNS) service, there are several for free:

- [afraid](http://freedns.afraid.org/)
- [BuddyNS](http://www.buddyns.com/)
- [Twisted4life](http://www.twisted4life.com/)

Find more services at this [list of secondary DNS services](http://www.frankb.us/dns/) page.

Comment: Ok, let's suppose that I want my nameservers appear as ns.mydomain.com, the only way to do this is setting up my own DNS server? or I can get my ns.mydomain.com using a external DNS service too?

Comment: You can get personalized names on external DNS services also. This requirement is usually called "Vanity DNS" and is usually paid.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the VPS hosting company, you can install and run your own nameserver on your VPS and have your nameserver like `ns.mydomain.com`. If you use the shared DNS, you will have to use the `ns1.hostingcompany.com` nameservers.

Comment: But I only have 1 IP, can I repeat the address for the second nameserver?

Comment: No, but you can give two names to the same IP. For a usual setup, I would stick with the shared DNS, mainly because a DNS server will "steal" your VPS resources without adding much.

Comment: obs: by names, I mean A records of course

Answer (score 0):

Your VPS hosting company may act as your secondary DNS servers, but for a small domain it may be just as well to use your domain registrar.  This can make lookups a little faster for those servers that need to look up you address.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason why at least 2 nameservers are required. Don't put both name servers on the same machine.

If you want to run your own DNS servers, set up another cheap VPS somewhere. It doesn't require a lot of resources. However, you'll need to learn about [BIND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND).

Answer (score 0):

create your both name server under 1 ip. Install bind on your VPS server. Configure Bind server and use your own Name server under your VPS server.